# How to restart informatica workflow after failed session?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have 10 session in informatica, it failed at 5th session , i want to run remaining 5 session except the failed one. failed session creates trigger for 6th and 7th session and 7th will create trigger for 8th and 8th to 9th and 9th to 10th. trigger for 6th and 7th are already present.

should i use restart workflow from task for 6th and 7th session or I should use restart task from 6th till 10th manually.

Answer (score 0):

Broad question, the answer is most probably yes but only you know if this is feasible for your workflow.

You may have 'fail this workflow if this session doesn't run' set on one of the earlier sessions in the workflow in which case the workflow will complete but report failure and need to be cold started on follow up run.

Have you successfully reran session 5 since the failure?

If there was no need for session 5 to finish successfully before starting 6 and 7 then why was the dependency there?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the design of the Workflow. There can be workflows designed to run from any task, there can be workflows designed to restart from the point of failure even. And there can be workflows that always have to be run from the very beginning. You need to check what's your case.